# what is the difference between [string()] and list() in erlang?

Tags: erlang

Erlang: what is the difference between [string()] and list() ??

I saw them as return types of ct_telnet:cmd and ct_ssh:exec ?

http://erlang.org/doc/man/ct_ssh.html

```
exec(SSH, Command, Timeout) -> {ok, Data} | {error, Reason}
Types:
  Data = list()
```

http://erlang.org/doc/man/ct_telnet.html

```
cmd(Connection, Cmd, Opts) -> {ok, Data} | {error, Reason}
Types:
  Data = [string()]
```

Answer (score 9):

The type `list()` stands for any list, without specifying the type of its elements.  Another way to write it is `[_]` or `[term()]`.

A `string()` is a special case of `list()`: it is a list containing integers representing Unicode code points (or Latin-1 characters, if less than 256, or ASCII characters, if less than 128).  Another way to write `string()` is `list(char())` or `[char()]`.

A `[string()]` is a list of strings.  This type can also be written as `list(string())`. Since it is a special case of a list, it is also valid (though less informative) to write it as `list()`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Is it same when any of the two types are passed to a function as below ?

 loop_list( [H | L])

Comment: @seenu9333 That of course depends on what the function accepts.

Comment: @seenu9333: function `loop_list([H | L])` accepts all `list(X)` (or `[X]` types) where `H` is expected to be type `X` and `T` of type `list(X)`.

Answer (score 0):

Formally there is no such type as "string" in Erlang, however strings are denoted using a list of codes. So essentially

String() -> [Positive_Integer()] (list of positive integers)

[String()] -> [[Positive_Integer()]]  (list of list of positive integers)

where [] denotes a list.